# how could I add hostname of all the containers based on the count to nginx upstream

Tags: docker, nginx, ansible

I have a ansible script that is creating n numbers of docker containers with their hostname and also it creates one nginx server. I am pushing one new conf using j2 templating.

How could I add the hostnames dynamically to that conf in upstream section?

```
upstream abc {
 server abc1.abc.com:181;
 server abc2.abc.com:181;

}
```

So if I change the count to 3 it should add  abc3

```
upstream abc {
 server abc1.abc.com:181;
 server abc2.abc.com:181;
 server abc3.abc.com

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lineinfile` module and `sequence` plugin to achieve that. I suppose the hostnames will always have the same pattern, so you can do something like this:

```
vars:
  container_count: 5 
  # You can set here the amount of containers you want to deploy

- name: Generate conf
  lineinfile:
    path: /you_conf_file_path/file.conf
    insertafter: '^upstream abc {'
    line: "server abc{{ idx + 1 }}.abc.com"
  with_sequence: count="{{ container_count }}"
  loop_control:
    index_var: idx
```

Hope this can point you to right direction...

Sources: [Sequence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/plugins/lookup/sequence.html) and [Lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html)

Comment: Is there a way to do it without index_var as I am using ansible 2.4 version

Comment: I cant think in a way without it, maybe theres another way of doing it but i dont know how... sorry =/